# Android Not Uploading All Properties to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload a class object to Firebase with Android, the class has 7 string properties and every property has getter/setter and the class has an empty constructor. But I am not getting the last Property i.e **startTime** in the database. Everything else is alright. I have tested the if that property has a valid String value. 
Here is the code for my Firebase Data Class:

```
public class MissingSignoffData {
public String name = "";
public String id = "";
public String busNumber = "";
public String startTime = "";
public String endTime = "";
public String phone = "";
public String date = "";

public MissingSignoffData(String name, String id, String busNumber,String startTime, String endTime, String phone, String date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.busNumber = busNumber;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.date = date;
}

public MissingSignoffData() {
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBusNumber() {
    return busNumber;
}

public void setBusNumber(String busNumber) {
    this.busNumber = busNumber;
}

public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

This is how I am uplaoding calss to firebase:

```
 //data is the object for class 
 mRef.child("myRecords").child(date).child(key).setValue(data);
```

Comment: Please show all of the code (the minimum required) that reproduces the result you're describing.  For example, we can't see how you're creating an instance of MissingSignoffData, and how you're populating it.

Comment: I think, `startTime` have `null` value that's why it is not storing in the database.

Comment: Please add the code that reproduces that behaviour. Show us how you're creating an instance of MissingSignoffData, and how you're populating it.